# 1 Error(s) Line 2 Column 84 : cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'w:document'. What is the error in this xml?

Tags: xml, formatting

When I validate the below XML code using http://xmlvalidator.new-studio.org/. It shows:

> Cannot find the declaration of element 'w:document'

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<w:document mc:Ignorable="w14 w15 wp14" xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape"> 
  <w:body>  
    <w:p w:rsidR="008F5349" w:rsidRDefault="00D13E73">  
      <w:r>  
        <w:t>USER REPORT</w:t>  
      </w:r>  
    </w:p>  
    <w:p w:rsidR="00D13E73" w:rsidRDefault="00D13E73" />  
    <w:p w:rsidP="00D13E73" w:rsidR="00D13E73" w:rsidRDefault="00D13E73">  
      <w:r>  
        <w:t>&lt;&lt;PartnerLegacyIdMapping Account#&gt;&gt;</w:t>  
      </w:r>  
    </w:p>         
  </w:body>  
</w:document>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the XML Validator web site that you are using, but from a quick glance, it only allows you to supply an XML document, and not to supply an XML Schema. Presumably therefore it is relying on the XML document containing a reference to the schema in an `xsi:schemaLocation` attribute. Your XML document doesn't contain such a reference, so the validator doesn't know where to find a schema.

Other XSD validators allow you to specify the schema to use independently of the source document (which is rather more helpful. I've always thought that the only reason you want to validate a document is because you don't trust it, and if you don't trust it, why would you trust it to identify its schema correctly?)